# Meaning of $e_i$ in a proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

In page $80$ of [this](http://xn--webducation-dbb.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Econometric-Exercises-1-Karim-M.-Abadir-Jan-R.-Magnus-Matrix-Algebra-Econometric-Exercises-Cambridge-University-Press-2005.pdf) book, Exercise 4.11 (Rank factorization theorem) proves that every $m\times n$ matrix $A$ of rank $r$ can be written as the sum of $r$ matrices of rank $1$. In the proof, the author eventually states that
$$
Ae_i=a_i=B(C'e_i)=(BC')e_i
$$
for all $i$.

> My question is: what does $e_i$ mean in this proof?

Comment: $e_i$: a vector with $i^{th}$ element as unity and rest zero.

Comment: They define it in page 3. Usually books have an index of Notation. This book has it at the end, as Apendix B: Notation. On page 416 it is defined as well.

Comment: Can anybody tell me what do you call this vector $e_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e_i$ is the $i$th member of the standard basis, that is $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ and so on until $e_n=(0,\ldots,0,1)^T$. Or, in analogy to the notation $a_i$ they use for the $i$th colun of matrix $A$, you may view $e_i$ as the $i$th column of the identity matrix.